# Norm (Number Field) is linear? (Am i making a huge mistake?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Given a Field of numbers $K:= \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$ of degree $n$. The Norm of $\alpha \in K $ is defined as $N_K(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_i(\alpha)$. Where $\sigma_i: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are the unique monomorphisms (injective Field homomorphisms) such that $\sigma_i(\theta) = \theta_i$, where $\theta_i$ are the roots (in $\mathbb{C}$) of the minimal polynomial of $\theta$.

Now, if i have a $(\omega_j)_{j=1}^n$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$: $N(\alpha=\sum_jc_j\omega_j)= \prod_i\sigma_i(\sum_jc_j \omega_j) = \prod_i\sum_j\sigma_i(c_j\omega_j)=\sum_j c_j\prod_i\sigma_i(\omega_j) = \sum_jc_jN(\omega_j)$

From which we can deduce for $\beta=\sum_jd_j \omega_j$ $N(\alpha + \beta) =  \sum_j(c_j + d_j)N(\omega_j) = \sum_jc_jN(\omega_j)+ \sum_jd_jN(\omega_j) = N(\alpha) + N(\beta)$

But this can't be right... Am i going nuts?

Comment: Field norm is certainly not linear beacuse it is not always true that $N(c \alpha)=c N(\alpha)$. In general for an extension $K/F$, we have $N_{K/F}(c \alpha)=c^{[K:F]} N(\alpha)$ for an scalar $c$. Field norm is multiplicative not additive

Comment: Yes. That is why i thought i was going nuts. The answer pointed out where my mistake lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\prod_i\sum_j\sigma_i(c_j\omega_j)=\sum_\alpha \prod_i \sigma_i(c_{\alpha_i}\omega_{\alpha_i}) \ne \sum_j c_j\prod_i\sigma_i(\omega_j)$$ where the sum over $\alpha=(\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_n)$ exhausts every $n$-tuple such that $1 \le \alpha_i \le n$ for each $i$.

Comment: You are completely right! Do you think i should delete this post? (I doubt that this specifically will be useful to many people)

Comment: @Pastudent, I appreciate your question. You should keep it. It might help others

Comment: @Pastudent when you get confused by such things, forget the full generality and just look at the first nontrivial case where you think your answer should be wrong, which happens already when $n = 2$: write everything out explicitly when $K$ is a quadratic field and then your computational error should be much simpler for you to find.